# Python doesn't read all files in a loop to concatinate pd dfs

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, export-to-csv

$1. This code works, put only for 4 files in my database. It does not read all files and append in frame. I am trying to concatenate multiple Trend.csv files (200) in a loop.

```
  frame =[]
  for raw_file_name in raw_files:
      input_raw_path = os.path.join(raw_path, raw_file_name, 'log.txt')
      if os.path.isfile (input_raw_path):
          with open(input_raw_path, encoding= "Latin-1") as f:
              ts = f.readline(19).split()[1]

              input_superecg_path = os.path.join(superecg_path, raw_file_name, 'Trend.csv')
              if os.path.isfile (input_superecg_path):
                  df = pd.read_csv(input_superecg_path)
                  df['File'] = raw_file_name
                  df['Time'] = pd.timedelta_range(ts, freq='T', periods=df.shape[0], name='Time')
                  df = pd.melt(df, id_vars = ['Time', 'File'], var_name = 'Parameter', value_name = 'Value')
                  frame.append(df)


  frame = pd.concat(frame, keys = ['Time','File','Parameter','Value'])
```

$2. I get my frame only for 4 files, instead of 200

```
    In [61]: frame.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
MultiIndex: 298688 entries, (Time, 0) to (Value, 74671)
Data columns (total 4 columns):
Time         298688 non-null timedelta64[ns]
File         298688 non-null object
Parameter    298688 non-null object
Value        237502 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(1), object(2), timedelta64[ns](1)
memory usage: 10.5+ MB

In [62]: frame.File.unique()
Out[62]: 
array(['ICC000013 RASESG0347  1', 'ICC000019  1',
   'ICC000020 RASESG0341  1', 'ICC000021 RASESG0075  1'],       dtype=object)
In [64]: len(raw_files)
Out[64]: 201
```

Comment: Are you sure the if equations are True for all files ? You should add an else: for both and print/log if something fails the check. From your original 200 files you are looking for a matching file with a different name twice so that could be an issue. Further it seem odd that you read only 19 bytes from a line then split it and use the second split item (assuming a date is in there for pd.timedelta_range). If you could provide the folder stucture there could be much easier ways to simply iterate over the files themselves.

Comment: Hi, thanks for comment.. Ifigured out)).  loop was ok, the problem was pd.concat().... it perfectly worked with frame = pd.concat(frame, ignore_index=True) ... although I didn't completely undersood why.. I had only that 4 coulms in each dfs.